# Developing Android on Sublime Text 2

Tags: android, installation, sublimetext2

I wanted to start developing for Android, but found it terribly hard to set everything up so it would work on Sublime Text 2.

I know that I'm supposed to download and set up the Android SDK, but how, where and why? And how do I compile my projects and run them? This is a complete mystery to me.

I've been researching this for about 3 hours now and haven't had any success. Could anyone of you, please, help me by guide me through the process of setting everything up in ST2?

Please note that I do not want to use Eclipse IDE. I've grown to love ST2 and I'd like to stick with it.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but this could be useful: https://github.com/dskinner/SublimeAndroid

Comment: Thanks @kabuko. You give us hope that someday we'll be able to drop buggy, slow IDEs like Eclipse. In the documentation, it says SublimeAndroid is slated for a Sublime Text 3 release!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that I'm supposed to download and set up the Android SDK, but how, where and why?

Visit the [official site](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and follow the instructions for "other/existing IDE". I don't think anyone wrote specific instructions for using Sublime yet though (since you haven't found one).

> And how do I compile my projects and run them? This is a complete mystery to me.

As others already answered, other than a JDK, you will most likely need to download and run [Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) from the command line.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want start Andriod development, without using the great support of an IDE like Intelji Idea or Eclipse, then you should properly look into [building and running](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html) your applications in the command line beside Sublime Text 2

Comment: The eventual release of Android Studio will change this pretty substantially. You can download a preview now if you'd like. Basically, the IDE runs all (I believe?) build and sign operations through a single command line interface (gradle). This makes it trivial to switch between IDE and non-IDE development.

Answer (score 1):

If you follow the instructions for using the 'Andrew' software module from github, you can get sublime to communicate with the android sdk and ant build tool via a tool called monitor.

https://github.com/Korcholis/Andrew

Kind of similar to a vim addon i used to use that talked to eclipse service.

But if anyone else is reading this, intellij (android studio) has come on leaps and bounds regarding speed and autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse and IntelliJ are the known supported IDEs for Android development. If you don't want to use Eclipse or IntelliJ, read up about ant scripts and how to build with Ant. That should get you started.

Sublime Text 2, right now doesn't support Android development from within the IDE. The only option you have, other than using Ant, is to wait for someone to write a plugin for that.